# Multiple timers on the same button

Tags: android

How can I make 4 timers of 10 mins countdown with the click of one button? All I could've done was one timer and the rest of them (3) stuck on 00:00. I know that I have to do the same thing I did to the one it's working but I made the first one a long time ago. Can someone explain me what to do and where to do it?

````
    private static final long START_TIME_IN_MILLIS = 600000;

    private TextView mTextViewCountDown;
    private TextView mTextViewCountDown_2;
    private TextView mTextViewCountDown_3;
    private TextView mTextViewCountDown_4;
    private Button mButtonStartPause;
    private Button mButtonReset;

    private CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer;

    private boolean mTimerRunning;

    private long mTimeLeftInMillis = START_TIME_IN_MILLIS;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);


        mTextViewCountDown = findViewById(R.id.text_view_countdown);
        mTextViewCountDown_2 = findViewById(R.id.text_view_countdown_2);
        mTextViewCountDown_3 = findViewById(R.id.text_view_countdown_3);
        mTextViewCountDown_4 = findViewById(R.id.text_view_countdown_4);

        mButtonStartPause = findViewById(R.id.button_start_pause);
        mButtonReset = findViewById(R.id.button_reset);

        mButtonStartPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mTimerRunning) {
                    pauseTimer();
                } else {
                    startTimer();
                }
            }
        });

        mButtonReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                resetTimer();
            }
        });

        updateCountDownText();
    }

    private void startTimer() {
        mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(mTimeLeftInMillis, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                mTimeLeftInMillis = millisUntilFinished;
                updateCountDownText();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                mTimerRunning = false;
                mButtonStartPause.setText("Start");
                mButtonStartPause.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                mButtonReset.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }.start();

        mTimerRunning = true;
        mButtonStartPause.setText("Pause");
        mButtonReset.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    private void pauseTimer() {
        mCountDownTimer.cancel();
        mTimerRunning = false;
        mButtonStartPause.setText("Start");
        mButtonReset.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    private void resetTimer() {
        mTimeLeftInMillis = START_TIME_IN_MILLIS;
        updateCountDownText();
        mButtonReset.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mButtonStartPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    private void updateCountDownText() {
        int minutes = (int) (mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000) / 60;
        int seconds = (int) (mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000) % 60;

        String timeLeftFormatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds);

        mTextViewCountDown.setText(timeLeftFormatted);
    }
} ```
````

Answer (score 0):

You basically have to make 3 more timer variables, 3 more mTimeLeftInMillis variables, start the other 3 timers, and then update the other 3 textviews the same way you have done with the first one.

So, you could do something like this (assuming you want to start/stop all 4 at the same time):

```
private CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer;
private CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer2;
private CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer3;
private CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer4;

private boolean mTimerRunning;

private long mTimeLeftInMillis = START_TIME_IN_MILLIS;
private long mTimeLeftInMillis2 = START_TIME_IN_MILLIS;
private long mTimeLeftInMillis3 = START_TIME_IN_MILLIS;
private long mTimeLeftInMillis4 = START_TIME_IN_MILLIS;
```

Then, in your `startTimer` method, you initialise the other 3 timers the same way you did the first one, using this:

```
mCountDownTimer2 = new CountDownTimer(mTimeLeftInMillis2, 1000) {...
mCountDownTimer3 = new CountDownTimer(mTimeLeftInMillis3, 1000) {...
mCountDownTimer4 = new CountDownTimer(mTimeLeftInMillis4, 1000) {...
```

The only difference in the body being the `updateCountDownText` method, because you will have to define 3 more methods to update each other textview to display each timer, maybe like this:

```
private void updateCountDownText2() {... // update mTextViewCountDown_2 in this method
private void updateCountDownText3() {... // update mTextViewCountDown_3 in this method
private void updateCountDownText4() {... // update mTextViewCountDown_4 in this method
```

Then use these new methods in your `mCountDownTimer2`, `mCountDownTimer3` and `mCountDownTimer4` definitions.

There are shorter ways to do it, but that's the gist of it.